# Событие не происходит по клику (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, javascript-events

Начинающий в JS, поэтому совершенно не могу понять, что делаю не так.
Нужно: отобразить/скрыть блок при нажатии определенной radio кнопки.

Написал такой скрипт:

```
const samo = document.getElementById('samo-block');

const _button = document.getElementById('dostavka');

const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="shipping_method[0]"]');
radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick);
});

function handleRadioClick() {
    if (_button.checked) {
        samo.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        samo.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Он не работает. Перебрал кучу вариантов, но не помогает. Делал алерты на переменные, все выводит, проблема именно с событием.
Делаю сайт на Wordpress.

Comment: Вы бы конечно добавили html свой для полноты картины. Могу предположить что здесь `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="shipping_method[0]"]')` лишний `0`, должно быть скорее всего `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="shipping_method[]"]')`.

Comment: @Simon, 0 не лишний, т.к это точное название атрибута name, на всякий случай попробовал вызвать функцию без клика, просто при загрузке страницы - она работает только с нулем.
По html - не совсем знаю, как добавить его сюда, т.к это форма checkout у Woocommerce, radio-кнопки - это выбор способа доставки, а искомый div крепится через хук 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details'. То есть они в разных местах кода. Но повторюсь, что если сама функция работает исправно, если активируется при запуске страницы. Но именно клик не работает.

Comment: @Simon загнал в codePen - все работает. Видимо, что-то конфликтует на странице. У меня есть плагин доставки СДЭК, который тоже в зависимости от выбранного типа доставки показывает или не показывает блок с картой ПВЗ. Может, с ним какая-то несовместимость. С другой стороны, странно, что все отображается если просто вызвать функцию при загрузке страницы, без появления/убирания по клику